# How to recursively create a directory in Qt?

Tags: qt, recursion, directory

Is there a function that given an absolute path will attempt to create all directories in the path that do not exist?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use

`bool QDir::mkpath(const QString &dirPath) const`

as described in the [`Qt4.x documentation`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdir.html#mkpath) and [`Qt5.x documentation`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#mkpath)

> Creates the directorypath dirPath.
>
> The function will **create all parent directories necessary** to create
>   the directory.
>
> Returns true if successful; otherwise returns false.
>
> If the path already exists when this function is called, it will
>   return true.

Comment: Yes but since this is not static (see [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-3943)), you will have to do `QDir().mkpath(...)`.