# Qt: how to create a file (with directorys required by its path)?

Tags: c++, file, qt

Qt: how to create a file with directorys required by its path? say create "./gg/ggg./fff/ff/file.dd" if it does not exist?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recursively create a directory in Qt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232631/how-to-recursively-create-a-directory-in-qt)

Answer (score 3):

you can set the path as

```
QDir directory("gg/ggg./fff/ff/file");
```

then you can create a folder like

```
QDir().mkdir("MyFolder");


bool QDir::mkdir ( const QString & dirName ) const
Creates a sub-directory called dirName.

Returns true on success; otherwise returns false.

See also rmdir().
```

refer http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#mkdir

```
bool QDir::mkpath ( const QString & dirPath ) const
Creates the directory path dirPath.

The function will create all parent directories necessary to create the directory.

Returns true if successful; otherwise returns false.
```

refer http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#mkpath

```
bool QFile::open ( OpenMode mode )   [virtual]
Reimplemented from QIODevice::open().

Opens the file using OpenMode mode, returning true if successful; otherwise false.
In WriteOnly or ReadWrite mode, if the relevant file does not already exist, this function will try to create a new file before opening it.
```

refer http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#open